# FIRST_VALUE and FULL OUTER JOIN to fill nulls with previous record does not work

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

My source data in our Snowflake data-warehouse has "gaps" i.e missing days and my requirement is to fill the missing data with that from the previous row. So I created this dummy project to practice working with full outer join and window function `FIRST_VALUE`.

My sample data has two tables: one called **prev_test**,  one called **dim_date**

```
create TABLE prev_test (
    SITE_ID VARCHAR(650),
    SUBSCRIPTION_ID VARCHAR(650),
    ORDER_CREATED DATE,
    ORDER_TYPE VARCHAR(650),
    SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS VARCHAR(650),
    PERIOD_NORMALIZER VARCHAR(650),
    CHANGE_MRR_EVENT_TYPE VARCHAR(650),
    TOTAL integer,
    DAILY_MRR integer
);

INSERT INTO prev_test 
VALUES('AB', '123', '2021-09-17', 'PRORATED', 'ACTIVE', '1M', 'New', 60, 2);
INSERT INTO prev_test 
VALUES('AB', '123', '2021-09-20', 'PRORATED', 'ACTIVE', '1M', 'New', 30, 10);

create TABLE dim_date (
  date_key date
  );
INSERT INTO dim_date 
VALUES('2021-09-17');
INSERT INTO dim_date 
VALUES('2021-09-18');
INSERT INTO dim_date 
VALUES('2021-09-19');
INSERT INTO dim_date 
VALUES('2021-09-20');
```

When I select my data thusly

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN SITE_ID IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(SITE_ID) OVER (ORDER BY ORDER_CREATED ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) ELSE SITE_ID END AS SITE_ID , 
CASE WHEN SUBSCRIPTION_ID IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(SUBSCRIPTION_ID) OVER (ORDER BY ORDER_CREATED ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) ELSE SUBSCRIPTION_ID END AS SUBSCRIPTION_ID , 
CASE WHEN ORDER_CREATED IS NULL THEN dd.DATE_KEY ELSE ORDER_CREATED END AS ORDER_CREATED, 
CASE WHEN ORDER_TYPE IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(ORDER_TYPE) OVER (ORDER BY ORDER_CREATED ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) ELSE ORDER_TYPE END AS ORDER_TYPE , 
CASE WHEN SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS) OVER (ORDER BY ORDER_CREATED ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) ELSE SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS END AS SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS , 
CASE WHEN PERIOD_NORMALIZER IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(PERIOD_NORMALIZER) OVER (ORDER BY ORDER_CREATED ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) ELSE PERIOD_NORMALIZER END AS PERIOD_NORMALIZER , 
CASE WHEN CHANGE_MRR_EVENT_TYPE IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(CHANGE_MRR_EVENT_TYPE) OVER (ORDER BY ORDER_CREATED ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) ELSE CHANGE_MRR_EVENT_TYPE END AS CHANGE_MRR_EVENT_TYPE , 
CASE WHEN TOTAL IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(TOTAL) OVER (ORDER BY ORDER_CREATED ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) ELSE TOTAL END AS TOTAL , 
CASE WHEN DAILY_MRR IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(DAILY_MRR) OVER (ORDER BY ORDER_CREATED ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) ELSE DAILY_MRR END AS DAILY_MRR  
FROM prev_test
FULL OUTER JOIN DIM_DATE dd ON ORDER_CREATED = dd.DATE_KEY 
ORDER BY 3 asc
```

[This gives the output that I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKsEa.png).

However, as soon as I apply the same code to my production data (same structure as my sample), it simply does not work. Missing days are not filled and FIRST_VALUE does not "repeat" data over to the following records. No errors.

This is an example of my "real" data

```
SITE_ID    |SUBSCRIPTION_ID       |ORDER_CREATED|ORDER_TYPE     |SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS|PERIOD_NORMALIZER|CHANGE_MRR_EVENT_TYPE  |TOTAL   |DAILY_MRR     |
L22|JriInfs|   2021-06-02|PRORATED|Active          |1M               |Upgraded From  |  0.0000|  0.000000|
L22|JriInfs|   2021-09-17|PRORATED|Active          |1M               |New             |209.0000|209.000000|
L22|JriInfs|   2021-09-30|PRORATED|Active          |1M               |Changed         |269.0000|269.000000|
L22|JriInfs|   2021-10-08|PRORATED|Active          |1M               |Downgraded From|  0.0000|  0.000000|
```

This is the output I want (the ** are the "missing" days), I hope this helps:

```
SITE_ID    |SUBSCRIPTION_ID       |ORDER_CREATED|ORDER_TYPE     |SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS|PERIOD_NORMALIZER|CHANGE_MRR_EVENT_TYPE  |TOTAL   |DAILY_MRR     |
L22|JriInfs|   2021-06-02|PRORATED|Active          |1M               |Upgraded From  |  0.0000|  0.000000|
**L22|JriInfs|   2021-06-03|PRORATED|Active          |1M               |Upgraded From  |  0.0000|  0.000000|**
…
**L22|JriInfs|   2021-09-16|PRORATED|Active          |1M               |Upgraded From  |  0.0000|  0.000000|**
L22|JriInfs|   2021-09-17|PRORATED|Active          |1M               |New             |209.0000|209.000000|
**L22|JriInfs|   2021-09-18|PRORATED|Active          |1M               |New             |209.0000|209.000000|**
…
**L22|JriInfs|   2021-09-29|PRORATED|Active          |1M               |New             |209.0000|209.000000|**
L22|JriInfs|   2021-09-30|PRORATED|Active          |1M               |Changed         |269.0000|269.000000|
...
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you provide a short example how your real data looks like?

Comment: @MΛIK I edited my post to add a sample of my real data.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your query is that the you are ordering based on `ORDER_CREATED`. The transformed value is not used here, Instead for the rows that are missing, the value is `NULL` and hence the result of `FIRST_VALUE` is NULL. You should order by `DATE_KEY` instead. However, ordering by `DATE_KEY` will still fetch you incorrect result as the missing rows will always get populated with the values of the first row. In your example, if you have another insert

```
INSERT INTO prev_test 
VALUES('AB', '123', '2021-09-23', 'PRORATED', 'ACTIVE', '1M', 'New', 30, 10);
```

The rows for dates 21st and 22nd will get values from the date of 17th(which is incorrect) rather than getting value from the 20th.

I tried the below query and it works. You can modify it to use `FIRST_VALUE`

```
select
case when site_id is not null then site_id 
else max(site_id) over(partition by c_val order by order_created) end as site_id,
case when SUBSCRIPTION_ID is not null then SUBSCRIPTION_ID
else max(SUBSCRIPTION_ID) over(partition by c_val order by order_created) end as SUBSCRIPTION_ID,
order_created
from
(select 
*,
sum(val)over(order by order_created rows unbounded preceding) as c_val from
(
  select
  site_id,
  subscription_id,
  coalesce(a.order_created,dd.DATE_KEY) as order_created,
  ORDER_TYPE,
  SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS,
  PERIOD_NORMALIZER,
  CHANGE_MRR_EVENT_TYPE,
  TOTAL,
  DAILY_MRR,
  case when a.order_created is null then 0 else 1 end as val
  FROM prev_test a
FULL OUTER JOIN DIM_DATE dd ON a.ORDER_CREATED = dd.DATE_KEY
WHERE  dd.DATE_KEY >=(select min(a.ORDER_CREATED) from prev_test)
)tbl) x
```

db fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c7dc8/3/0

EDIT : Added condition to filter dates' start point.

Comment: That does not work with my production data. Same issue as me.

Comment: Did u check the fiddle? It works. There must be a new scenario that u r not explaining in your question. Edit your question to add sample input that doesn't work, I'll be able to fix the query.

Comment: I checked your fiddle and yeah it works great. I edited my post to add a sample of my real data.

Comment: Does your dim_date table have all the dates? Perhaps, add the output that you are expecting. Maybe a couple of rows and an explanation.

Comment: The dim_date table has all the dates all the way to year 2100. I have added to my original post the output I am expecting. Hope this helps.

Comment: that's weird. This query should work. However, you might have to tweak the query to fetch data only from the minimum date in the table.

Comment: I agree, that's weird. I'll give your suggestion a try.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to my problem

```
SELECT DISTINCT
CASE 
WHEN srm.SITE_ID IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(srm.SITE_ID) OVER (ORDER BY dd.DATE_KEY ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) ELSE srm.SITE_ID END AS SITE_ID, 
CASE WHEN srm.SUBSCRIPTION_ID IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(SUBSCRIPTION_ID) OVER (ORDER BY  dd.DATE_KEY ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) ELSE srm.SUBSCRIPTION_ID END AS SUBSCRIPTION_ID , 
DD.DATE_KEY AS ORDER_CREATED,
CASE WHEN srm.ORDER_TYPE IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(srm.ORDER_TYPE) OVER (ORDER BY  dd.DATE_KEY ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) ELSE srm.ORDER_TYPE END AS ORDER_TYPE , 
CASE WHEN srm.SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS) OVER (ORDER BY  dd.DATE_KEY ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) ELSE srm.SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS END AS SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS , 
CASE WHEN srm.PERIOD_NORMALIZER IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(PERIOD_NORMALIZER) OVER (ORDER BY  dd.DATE_KEY ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) ELSE srm.PERIOD_NORMALIZER END AS PERIOD_NORMALIZER , 
CASE WHEN srm.CHANGE_MRR_EVENT_TYPE IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(CHANGE_MRR_EVENT_TYPE) OVER (ORDER BY  dd.DATE_KEY ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) ELSE srm.CHANGE_MRR_EVENT_TYPE END AS CHANGE_MRR_EVENT_TYPE , 
CASE WHEN srm.TOTAL IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(TOTAL) OVER (ORDER BY  dd.DATE_KEY ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) ELSE srm.TOTAL END AS TOTAL , 
CASE WHEN srm.DAILY_MRR IS NULL THEN FIRST_VALUE(DAILY_MRR) OVER (ORDER BY  dd.DATE_KEY ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) ELSE srm.DAILY_MRR END AS DAILY_MRR  
FROM DIM_DATE dd
    LEFT JOIN SUBSCRIPTION_REVENUE_MART srm 
        ON  srm.ORDER_CREATED = dd.DATE_KEY
ORDER BY dd.DATE_KEY;
```

The changes are as follows:

- the join was changed from FULL to LEFT
- the order of the tables was flipped
- instead of pulling ORDER_CREATED, the query pulls DATE_KEY in the SELECT clause